# Limiting the append instance on a dynamic content

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  var maxRows = 3;
  var x = 1;
  var json_url = "data_json.php";

  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td>';
  html += '<select name="dropdown_one[]" class="option_one">';
  html += '<option selected></option>';
  html += '</select>';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '<td>';
  html += '<select name="dropdown_two[]" class="option_two">';
  html += '<option selected></option>';
  html += '</select>';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '<td>';
  html += '<input type="number" step=0.01 name="amount[]"/>';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '<td>';
  html += '<button type="button" id="remove">Remove</button>';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '</tr>';

  $("#sample_table").on('click', '#add', function(e) {

    if (x <= maxRows) {
      $("#sample_table").append(html);
      x++;
    };
  });

  $("#sample_table").on('click', '#remove', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    x--;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sample_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Option one</th>
    <th>Option two</th>
   <th>Amount</th>
   <th><button type="button" id="add">Add</button></th>
     </tr>
   </thead>

 </table>
```

I have a dynamic add/remove drop down box and the values of the drop down gets appended from JSON.

The problem is every time I add another instance of the drop down, the option values of the select elements gets doubled. For example, let say that on the first instance the option values are A, B, C on the second one, the select option values will also be A, B, C but the previous one or the initial one will now become A, B, C, A, B, C it gets doubled. And now if I add another instance the values of the first one will get tripled, and the second one will get doubled.

```
$("#sample_table").click(function() {
  jQuery.getJSON(json_url, function(data) {

  $(".option_one").html("");
      $(".option_one").append("<option value='0' disabled selected></option>");

      jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $(".option_one").append('<option value="' + val.option_one + '"data-option_one_id="' + val.option_one_id + ' ">' + val.option_one + '</option>')
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet or access to the webpage?

Comment: @AdamBeleko I apologize I cannot provide a sample that includes retrieving of data from the mysql database, but only how the code behave. I included a snippet I hope that it will suffice.